# Value going into negative numbers - How to stop it?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, function, numbers

I have a small upgrade system were a user can either increase or decrease they're Health and Defence status by using the directional arrows on the screen. Basically, I've made it so that when you either increase or decrease the stats, the remaining points either goes up or down accordingly. The problem is that when both the values of Health and Defence both hit zero, and you press to push the button decrease/increase the stats after all the points have gone the points goes into negative numbers.

I'm wondering if there is a way to make it so that when a user has used all they're stat points, the stat number recognizes that they're all used and doesn't go into negative numbers. This is coded in AS3. Here is my code.

```
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, healthScore);
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, defenceScore);
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, remainPoints);

decBtnDef.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, decreaseDefenceDef);
incBtnDef.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, increaseDefenceDef);
decBtnHP.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, decreaseHealthHP);
incBtnHP.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, increaseHealthHP);

function healthScore (event:Event){
healthShow.text = String (health);
}
function defenceScore (event:Event){
defenceShow.text = String (defence);
}
function remainPoints (event:Event){
pointsShow.text = String (points);
}

var health:Number = 10;
var defence:Number = 10;
var points:Number = 10;

_test3.text = "You have"; pointsShow.text = String (points); _pointstxt.text = "points.";
_test.text = "You have"; healthShow.text = String (health); _healthtxt.text = "health.";
_test2.text = "You also have"; defenceShow.text = String (defence); _deftxt.text =     "defence.";

function increaseDefenceDef (e:MouseEvent):void{ //when mouse click on up btn
if (defence >= 0)
    defence +=1;
    points -=1;
} 

function decreaseDefenceDef (e:MouseEvent):void{ //when mouse click on down btn
if (defence > 0)
defence -= 1;
points +=1;
}

function increaseHealthHP (e:MouseEvent):void{ //when mouse click on up btn
if (health >= 0)
    health +=1;
    points -=1;
} 

function decreaseHealthHP (e:MouseEvent):void{ //when mouse click on down btn
if (health > 0)
health -= 1;
points +=1;
}
```

Comment: Have a read through of [this documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7fce.html).

Comment: There is no need for three ENTER_FRAME listeners also - you can put all three text expressions in one single ENTER_FRAME listener

Answer (score 0):

```
   function increaseDefenceDef (e:MouseEvent):void
   { //when mouse click on up btn
        if (points >= 1)
        {
            defence +=1;
            points -= 1;
        }
    } 

    function decreaseDefenceDef (e:MouseEvent):void
    { //when mouse click on down btn
        if (defence >= 1)
        {
            defence -= 1;
            points += 1;
        }
    }

    function increaseHealthHP (e:MouseEvent):void
    { //when mouse click on up btn
        if (points >= 1)
        {
            health +=1;
            points -= 1;
        }
    } 

    function decreaseHealthHP (e:MouseEvent):void
    { //when mouse click on down btn
        if (health >= 1)
        {
        health -= 1;
        points += 1;
        }
    }
```

Comment: yeah, because it's missing embraces conditionals

Comment: i added embraces to my answer, try again